# The type ' ' has no constructors defined c# initialize class

Tags: c#, wpf, class, overriding

I want to get recycler status from this device (BNR-bill acceptor) and i have problem with it.

When i want to initialize class

```
Recycler rec = new Recycler();
```

I get an error:

> The type 'Mei.Bnr.Module.Recycler.Recycler' has no constructors defined

Here is a screen from object browser. I will be gratefull for any suggestion.

[image]

Comment: It's also possible that the library creators have a factory of some sort that will construct those for you and give you an instance, instead of being able to instantiate directly.

Comment: How to use this instance? Any samle of symilar problem?